# Mac OS X gethostuuid function

Tags: macos, uuid

It appears that a "gethostuuid" function was added in Mac OS X 10.6:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/gethostuuid.2.html

Is there any documentation for how it generates the UUID? For example, do we know if it uses the guidelines from this technical note:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn1103/_index.html

Or something different? I'm wondering if this function is something that would be used alongside the guidelines from TN1103, or instead of them.

Comment: I did a pretty thorough search across http://opensource.apple.com and couldn't find the actual implementation of it, aside from the unistd.h declaration (`gethostuuid` came in with iOS 2.0 and Leopard, b.t.w.). This may be one of those cases where only Apple people know (and under strict NDA, no less). You should probably file a documentation bug and see if the doc team can improve the man page to have a sentence or two on how this uuid is generated.

Comment: My concern is that will this function return stable ID even mac upgraded to newer versions.   Anyone test this ?